# Three.js calculate .obj size (bottom and top position.y)

Tags: position, size, three.js

How can I calculate object bottom position?
I created an object and a plane, both in (0,0,0) position, but the model geometrical center is placed in that point, not the bottom face of it, in result, the plane is clipping the half of it, see the demo: http://www.edar.com.pl/test-3d-3/

I'd like my models to have the same height when I place them on the screen. Also I want them all to intersect the shadow plane with their bottom parts, so I guess I have to calculate their heights and move them via object.position.y = obj_height/2; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Three.GeometryUtils.Center() - function which centers the geometry of an object. 
So you could copy and modify the function to your liking to center the geometry at the bottom center.

Also you could also iterate over all vertices and just add or remove an offset-vector.